# Having trouble with recursion in Java

Tags: java

i have this matrix:

```
true,  false, true,  false, false
true,  false, true,  true,  true
false, false, false, false, true
true,  true,  false, true,  true
false, false, false, true,  false
```

and i want to have a function that checks if i have a "path" of 'trues' from the top to the bottom, like:

```
 true,  false, *true*, false,  false
 true,  false, *true*, *true*, *true*
 false, false, false,  false,  *true*
 true,  true,  false,  *true*, *true*
 false, false, false,  *true*, false
```

here's what i've done so far, but somehow isn't working:

```
public static boolean[][] findPath(int size, boolean[][] matrix) {

        boolean[][] matrix2;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {

                if ((matrix[i][j] == true) && (matrix[i + 1][j] == true)) {

                    return findPath(size, matrix[i + 1][j]);

                } else if ((matrix[i][j] == true) && (matrix[i][j + 1] == true)) {

                    return findPath(size, matrix[i][j + 1]);

                } else if ((matrix[i][j] == true) && (matrix[i][j - 1] == true)) {

                    return findPath(size, matrix[i][j - 1]);

                } else
                    return findPath(size, matrix[i][j+1]);

            }
        }

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what part is not working, can you give us some output you have gotten?

Comment: the code does not compile on eclipse, on the recursion call it says there's something wrong @jgr208

Comment: ah gotcha. hmmm what is the error eclipse says?

Comment: well you don't have a return statement for when the for loops don't execute

Comment: it has to do with the return type of the function. i got it because i'm returning a boolean and the should be returning a matrix, the problem is i have no idea how to fix it @jgr208

Comment: FYI, the algorithm you want to implement here is probably **[depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Pseudocode)**. Even if you don't use the pseudo-code there, it's good to be aware that there's a standard name for this type of search problem.

Comment: Why should it return a `boolean[][]`?  What would a proper output look like for your provided example?

Comment: You are not returning a boolean.  You are not returning anything.  It is pretty obvious, your function ends without a return statement.  Add a return statement.

Comment: Also you are calling `findPath(size, matrix[index][index])` which is like calling `findPath(int, boolean)` but I do not see that method declared anywhere.

Comment: `return findPath(size, matrix[i + 1][j]);` will not call findPath(int, boolean[][]) but findPath(int, boolean).

Comment: @MikeNakis the final else statement doesn't cover all the other cases, in case the if's don't check out ?

Comment: @laker001 no, think about a situation where you pass an empty `boolean[][]` the for loops won't even execute

Comment: @laker001 - It doesn't cover the case when `size <= 0`, in which case the loops get skipped. (This isn't really a valid input—but the compiler has no way to know that.)

Comment: yeah i know. this was my mistake, but in this specific exercise, the book says to assume the input is always right

Comment: @laker001 the JVM doesn't really care about what your book says hehe

Comment: The compiler has to be able to compile your program without knowing anything about your input, nor about your assumptions about your input.  Your program is missing a return statement. Add it, and it will compile.  Then, good luck making it work.  Case closed.  Move on.

Comment: @laker001 - Instead of adding a return statement at the end, you could add a statement that throws an exception, and that should make the compiler stop complaining. Something like this would be fitting: `throw new RuntimeException("Invalid input");`